# Power Query transform dataset with unique id's and extend columns

Tags: excel, powerquery

Straight to the point:

I need to turn a dataset (source from a CSV file) into a new table in Excel using power query editor (M language). The Product code in the example below should be unique, and for every URL there should be a new column, the name of the column could be "1-x" or "column 1-x", it doesn't matter. Just if the "IsDefault".value = 1, then it should go to the first column, for the 0 values, it doesn't matter (maybe from top to bottom would be perfect).

Source:
[image: Here's a picture of the dataset]

```
ProductCode,URL,IsDefault
1,a,1
2,b,1
2,c,0
3,d,0
2,e,0
3,f,1
```

Goal:

```
ProductCode,column1,column2,column3
1,a,null,null,null
2,b,c,e
3,f,d,null,null
```

I already achieved to count them with grouping, but I can't figure out how to add the number of columns from the maximum value and then how to transform this into the new table.

```
let
    Quelle = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\name\Desktop\cat-images-test.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Höher gestufte Header" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Quelle, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Gruppierte Zeilen" = Table.Group(#"Höher gestufte Header", {"ProductCode"}, {{"Anzahl", each Table.RowCount(Table.Distinct(_)), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Gruppierte Zeilen"
```

This code counts how many columns I need to insert, it's the max value of the column "Anzahl". There was no such scenario on other threads and I'm not very good in M language.

[image: Here's a picture of the count.]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the column on ProductCode, choosing All Rows for the URL aggregation. That will give you a new column with a Table for each row (I called it URLs). Now add a custom column using the formula:

```
=Table.Column([URLs], "URL")
```

which will produce List for each row. Click the little button in the top right of the new list column and choose Extract Values, and specify a comma delimiter. You can then Split this new column on the comma to create new columns to get your desired result.

Comment: Wow, perfect solution. Now I know how to handle these lists and extract value. Thank you very much.